# How to set the workdir of a container launched by Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is it possible to set the working directory when launching a container with Kubernetes ?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Yes, through the `workingDir` field of the [container spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#Container). Here's an example replication controller with an nginx container that has `workingDir` set to `/workdir`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: mynginximage
          workingDir: /workdir
```

Comment: Is there a indentation issue around `spec:` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming *when launching the container* implies setting working directory at container startup time. If not, using `workingDir` parameter as [answered above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36634736/13451415) works. I wanted the container launch `command` to work with a preset working directory and so I used the following pattern:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: <name>
          image: <image>
          command: ["/bin/bash"]
          args: ["-c", "cd /<my_workdir>; exec <my_command>;"]
```

Answer (score -4):

It should be also possible to set the working directory using env and command attributes. Below is an example:

```css
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: print-greeting
spec:
  containers:
  - name: env-print-demo
    image: bash
    env:
    - name: GREETING
      value: "Warm greetings to"
    - name: HONORIFIC
      value: "The Most Honorable"
    - name: NAME
      value: "Kubernetes"
    command: ["echo"]
    args: ["$(GREETING) $(HONORIFIC) $(NAME)"]
```