# How to configure docker entrypoint in Helm charts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have the following `docker-compose` file and I don't get how I can set the `working_dir` and `entrypoint` in the helm `deployment.yaml`. Does someone have an example on how to do this?

`docker-compose`

```
version: "3.5"
services:               
    checklist:
        image: ...
        working_dir: /checklist
        entrypoint: ["dotnet", "Checklist.dll"]        
        ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Helm uses Kubernetes [`Deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) with a different terminology than Docker. You'll want to define:

- `command` in Helm for `entrypoint` in Docker Compose (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316361/difference-between-docker-entrypoint-and-kubernetes-container-spec-command))
- `workingDir` in Helm for `working_dir` in Docker Compose (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634614/how-to-set-the-workdir-of-a-container-launched-by-kubernetes))

For your example it would be:

```
...
containers:
 - name: checklist
   ...
   command: ["dotnet", "Checklist.dll"] # Docker entrypoint equivalent
   workingDir: "/checklist" # Docker working_dir equivalent
```

Comment: I searched the whole day for `workingDir`. Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding another answer as the existing one did not work for me (in Open Shift), it resulted in the error:

```
starting container process caused "exec: \"dotnet Checklist.dll\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

What worked for me was overriding the entry point like this:

```
containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          command: "dotnet"
          args: "Checklist.dll"
```