# Overwrite entrypoint in Dockerfile without using the command "docker run"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, kubernetes-helm, docker-entrypoint

I have a problem with overwriting the entrypoint in my Dockerfile. For this (as I know) `docker run` with `--entrypoint` option is used, e.g.:

```
docker run --entrypoint "python3 main_script.py DEV"
```

However, in my case I can't use the `docker run` command because I have to use Helm charts for the deployments.

Is there an alternative to `docker run` using Helm charts, or other alternatives/solutions that I may not have thought of?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/57043161/8429943 work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use Helm charts for the deployments

This is easy: Kubernetes `command:` overrides Docker `ENTRYPOINT` (and Kubernetes `args:` matches Docker `CMD`).  So your Deployment spec can just say

```yaml
command:
  - python3
  - main_script.py
  - {{ .Values.environment }}
```

Usually, though, you shouldn't need to override `ENTRYPOINT`, especially in a `docker run` context.  An `ENTRYPOINT` isn't required, and it's very easy to override `CMD` at the end of the `docker run` line.  So if you change your Dockerfile to say

```sh
CMD python3 some_other_script.py
# with no ENTRYPOINT
```

then you can

```sh
docker run my-image \
  python3 main_script.py DEV
```

If that's not an option, then you need to be aware of the limitation that `docker run --entrypoint` only takes a single shell word.  That means the first word of your command goes with `--entrypoint` and is a Docker option (before the image name), and the rest is interpreted as a command (after the image name).

```sh
docker run \
  --entrypoint python3 \
  my-image \
  main_script.py DEV
```

Answer (score 2):

First you may set the command as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69242677/15087442. This is desribed in detail in the kubernetes documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

But there's also another option: You can change the entrypoint of the docker image. If it is your own docker image that's a no-brainer. But let's consider you are using someone elses image. Then you can modify it by building another image out of it. Dockerfile:

```
FROM old_image:latest

ENTRYPOINT python3 main_script.py DEV
```

And then you build the image with `docker build .`, push it to your preferred docker repository with `docker push` and use that one instead of the original one.

This is mostly interesting if you also want to modify other things in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had to use only one docker image, I tried the *helm charts* variant that was suggested by David after I got more involved with the topic helm charts and I can say: this worked for me.

My **solution** looked like this in the end:

```
command: ["python3"]       
args: ["main_script.py", "{ .Values.command.env }"]
```

In the *values.yaml* i added the following:

```
command: 
    env: "DEV"
```

And with that I could solve my problem with your help.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions and your help!